# What does this mean? "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4, http-status-code-405

I am using TinyMCE and the spell check option doesnt work. 
When I tried to check in developer tools - console - the error which it throws is:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Was just wondering what does this mean? The respective JS file very well exists in the folder. Not sure why this problem occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Something is causing an HTTP request to be made to the server. The server is telling you that the [method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) (POST, GET, PUT, etc) that you are using is not allowed for the URL that you are requesting.

This is almost certainly a server configuration issue.

As the next step in debugging, use the Net tab in your developer tools to determine which URL is returning that error, and for what method.

Comment: The interesting part beside the URL is that the Net tab will also show the actual method used for the request  ;)